# Nginx : add GET parameter if not present

Tags: nginx

I'm using Nginx to (among other things) act as a proxy for [Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/index.jsp) on my local machine (i.e. Nginx has a `proxy_pass` setting to redirect all traffic directed to `subsonic.mydomain.com` towards `localhost:4040`).

When accessing the main view without any GET parameters (`/home.view`), Subsonic shows the Random page, with random albums from my library. The Recently Added page is accessible by clicking a link to `/home.view?listType=newest`) but I would like it to be the default, without messing with Subsonic's code as this would break when updating Subsonic.

Using a simple `rewrite` doesn't seem like a solution because rewrites take only URIs into account, without the GET parameters. Therefore rewriting `^/home.view$` as `/home.view?listType=newest` will always show the Recently Added page even when I request other pages.

I would like to add the `listType` parameter only if it is not already present in the request, or add it in such a way that it gets overriden by the value in the request if it exists. Is there a way to do that in Nginx?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808667/alternative-of-else-operator-and-not-equal-operator-in-nginx/25889032#25889032), namely setting a variable to 0, then setting it to 1 if the parameter exists, and finally rewriting if the variable is still 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
location /home.view {
    if ( $arg_listType = '') {
        rewrite ^ /home.view?listType=newest last;
    }
    proxy_pass ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: I thought it worked but actually Nginx rejected the config file because of the "!". Are you sure your syntax is ok?

Comment: Fixed it a few hours ago using another method, see the answer I posted. Thanks for the help though!